# Gii ModelGenerator is not working in yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

Gii ModelGenerator is not working in yii Framework no any errors showing
in network, but when we hover on the ModelGenerator link **Waiting for localhost...**, my code in main.php looks like

```
'modules' => array(  
'gii' => array(  
'class'      => 'system.gii.GiiModule',  
'password'   => 'rajesh',  
'ipFilters'  => array('127.0.0.1:8080', '::1'),  
'generatorPaths' => array(  
'ext.giix-core',  
),  
),  
),
```

I have checked in Source Code: framework/gii/GiiModule.php in that
protected function allowIp($ip) the $ip value contains ::1 can anyone please   help me to improve this, beacause iam new to yii framework..

Comment: You have  ipFilter set to localhost  only .. then you can't use in remote .. (and this is the better way)

Comment: yes but i have worked with yii 1.1.3 version, but i have downloaded yii1.1.18 now it's working perfectly, thanks for your contribution, and iam hoping to communicate with you in future...